# How to generate WSDL with Ant in JDK11?

Tags: java, ant, wsdl, wsdl2java, java-11

Our project is upgrading from JDK8 to JDK11.
When generating the WSDL with ant I receive an error.
I have worked for this for several days, but didn't find any solution.

```
<path id="wsgen.main.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dir.externalLib}/jaxws-ri2.3.0/lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
...
<target name="generate_linux_wsdl">
    <delete dir="${dir.temp}/WSDL"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dir.temp}/WSDL"/>    
    <java classname="com.sun.tools.ws.WsGen">
     <arg value="-d"/>
     <arg value="${dir.temp}/WSDL"/>
     <arg value="-r"/>
     <arg value="${dir.temp}/WSDL"/>
     <arg value="-cp"/>
     <arg value="${wsgen.linux.classpathforrps}"/>
     <arg value="${linux.serviceimpl.class}"/>
     <arg value="-wsdl"/>   
     <arg value="-servicename"/>
     <arg value="${linux.service.name}"/>
     <classpath refid="wsgen.main.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

this is ant file.

```
 [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException: javax.jws.WebService missing element name
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:861)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:231)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [java]     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(UnknownSource)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [java]     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(UnknownSource)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException: javax.jws.WebService missing element name
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:163)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
 [java]     at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(WsgenTool.java:197)
 [java]     at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:128)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 [java]     at com.sun.tools.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:153)
 [java]     at com.sun.tools.ws.WsGen.main(WsGen.java:56)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:218)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:155)
 [java]     ... 32 more
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException: javax.jws.WebService missing element name
 [java]     at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:83)
 [java]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.name(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitType(WebServiceVisitor.java:144)
 [java]     at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitType(WebServiceVisitor.java:82)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:1447)
 [java]     at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAp.process(WebServiceAp.java:188)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:972)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:888)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1214)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1326)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:936)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
 [java]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
 [java]     ... 48 more
 [java] Java Result: -1
```

I don't know where the error is.
I can confirm this ant task is working in jdk8. After upgrading to jdk11, I included jaxws-ri2.3.0